# Keeping images stationary when resizing window

Tags: html, css, image

The images on my web page move and get jumbled when resizing window. What do I include in the CSS img tag to keep them stationary regardless of window size?

Comment: Wow... so many haters.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the images in a div and set a fixed width like so:

```
     <div style="width: 1200px">
          <img src="images/Hortilux1000.jpg" class="bulbs">
          <img src="images/DigiMax1000.jpg" class="bulbs">
          <img src="images/Sunmaster1000.jpg" class="bulbs">
          <img src="images/Ultra%20Sun%201000.jpg" class="bulbs">
     </div>
```

Comment: and fix the image width as well. Right now it seems like they are max-width, min-width etc. and you're maybe working with a responsive theme or something. Just use straight width and height. `bulbs: width: 200px; height: 200px;`